# How to detect if a view is visible in a viewport or window in react native?

Tags: react-native

I want a similar feature just like [react visibility sensor](https://github.com/joshwnj/react-visibility-sensor), but in react-native. I have a flat list with multiple items(each having different height). I want to detect whether a particular item(lets say 5th item) comes inside the view port and when it goes out

Answer (score 22, accepted):

You can use [`onViewableItemsChanged`](https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/flatlist#onviewableitemschanged) to check which `viewableItems` are on the screen.

Here's a dummy class example:

```
class Demo extends Component {
  constructor() {
    super();
    this.viewabilityConfig = {
      viewAreaCoveragePercentThreshold: 95
    }
  }
  onViewableItemsChanged = ({ viewableItems }) => {
    // viewableItems will show you what items are in view
  }
  render() {
    <FlatList
      ...
      onViewableItemsChanged={this.onViewableItemsChanged}
      viewabilityConfig={this.viewabilityConfig}
    />
  }
}
```

You'll need to modify [`viewAreaCoveragePercentThreshold`](https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/flatlist#viewareacoveragepercentthreshold) accordingly.

Comment: If you are using hooks in React Native, you will need to wrap that function and viewabilityConfig into Ref so the "Changing onViewableItemsChanged on the fly is not supported" error is not thrown. Please, see: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48045696/flatlist-scrollview-error-on-any-state-change-invariant-violation-changing-on/64573345

Answer (score 4):

You can use **Viewport** from **'@skele/components'** like this:

**0.** Install Skele Components:
yarn add @skele/components or npm install @skele/components

**1.** Wrap your scrollable view with Viewport.Tracker

```
    import { Viewport } from '@skele/components'
    ...
    render() {
        return (
            <Viewport.Tracker>
                <ScrollView scrollEventThrottle={16}>
                    { this.props.children }
                </ScrollView>
            </Viewport.Tracker>
        );
    }
```

**2.** Make its child components Viewport.Aware

```
import { Image } from 'react-native'
import { Viewport } from '@skele/components'
...
const ViewportAwareImage = Viewport.Aware(Image)
...
render() {
    return (
        <ViewportAwareImage
            source={{ uri: 'https://facebook.github.io/react-native/img/header_logo.png' }}
            onViewportEnter={() => console.log('Entered!')}
            onViewportLeave={() => console.log('Left!')} 
        />
    );
}
```

for more info visite [this link](https://blog.netcetera.com/viewport-aware-components-for-react-native-apps-a28ea605e89e)