# Setting a ref from with another useRef

Tags: react-native, react-native-flatlist, react-functional-component, use-ref

I have a `flatlist` and inside the `onViewableItemsChangedRef` I want to set the value of another `ref` inside the component like so:

```
const MyComponent= (): JSX.Element => {
    const currentId = useRef('');

    const onViewableItemsChangedRef = useRef(({ viewableItems }) => {
        // I want to set currentId in here
    });

    return (
        <FlatList
            // other props here like data, renderItem, etc.
            ref={ref}
            keyExtractor={(item) => item.id
            onViewableItemsChanged={onViewableItemsChangedRef.current}
        />
    );
};
```

But when I try to set `currentId.current` inside of `onViewableItemsChangedRef`, it's always `undefined`.

I tried switching the `useRef` to `useCallback` instead, but I would keep getting the error listed here [React Native FlatList onViewableItemsChanged callback encounter error after state changed rerender](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64089808/react-native-flatlist-onviewableitemschanged-callback-encounter-error-after-stat)

Is there another way of doing this?

Answer (score 0):

onViewableItemsChangedRef.current contains the first function definition which is bound to the first values, instead you can use useCallback calling a ref function like this:

```js
    const onViewableItemsChangedRef = useRef()
    onViewableItemsChangedRef.current = ({ viewableItems }) => {
        // I want to set currentId in here
    });
    onViewableItemsChanged = useCallback((...args)=>onViewableItemsChangedRef.current(...args),[])
    // now use onViewableItemsChanged instead of onViewableItemsChangedRef.current
```

Of course, you can use the effective arguments instead of `...args`

Comment: Hmm, could you show a complete example if you get the chance? I'm seeing this error: `Cannot redeclare block-scoped variable 'onViewableItemsChangedRef'.` on `const onViewableItemsChangedRef = useRef()` now.